# Express - JWT Cookie not being stored in browser

Tags: express, cookies, mongoose

I am trying to store a JWT in cookies in the browser so that I can keep reusing it for doing API calls trough protected routes.

The code below is a login script (without error handling to make it easier to read here), which checks if users email and password matches the one in the database.

```js
const auth = (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body
    User.findOne({ email }, async (err, user) => {

      // If password is correct, create token and send it back
      if (user && bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
        const token = await jwt.sign(
          { id: user._id },
          config.auth.secret,
          { expiresIn: config.auth.expireTime }
        )

        res
          .status(200)
          .cookie('access_token', token, {
            secure: false,
            maxAge: 120000,
            httpOnly: false,
          })
          .json({
            message: 'User found',
            user
          })

        return
      }
      // Wrong email or password
      res.status(401).json({ message: 'Wrong Email/Password', data: null })
    })
    return
  }
```

I set the cookie to be `httpOnly: false` as I thought that was the only way for the browser to be able to read it. This is what I see in the browser after logging in:

[image: no cookies in Application (chrome dev tools)]

No cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sending cookies from the backend, I sent it in the response headers on login, and then stored the cookie on the frontend by using this package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie

I now can reuse the cookie on future API calls after logging in (in my case to fetch todo items, folders, etc).